# Real-time stdout from subprocess in Python executable zip

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I wrote a program which runs a shell command in a new subprocess, and then polls it for content in the stdout buffer until it finishes running or reaches a timeout. This is part of a larger project which I am using to automate Docker builds.

```py
    def run(self, command: str) -> ShellProcess:
        log(f"Running command `{command}`...")

        start_time = time.time()

        process = subprocess.Popen(
            command,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True, shell=True,
            bufsize=1,
            universal_newlines=True,
            env=self.environment
        )

        output = []

        while line := process.stdout.readline():
            output.append(line)
            print(line.strip())

            if self.timeout is not None:
                elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                if elapsed_time > self.timeout:
                    log(
                        f"{int(elapsed_time)} seconds have elapsed, exceeding the timeout... "
                        f"forcefully terminating process."
                    )
                    process.terminate()

        # Wait for the process to finish
        _, error = process.communicate()

        if error:
            log("Contents of stderr buffer:")
            print(error.strip())
            log("End stderr buffer")

        elapsed_time = int(time.time() - start_time)

        log(f"Process returned with status code {process.returncode} in {elapsed_time} seconds.")

        output = "".join(output)

        process = ShellProcess(
            command, output, error,process.returncode
        )

        return process
```

I am testing by running the following Python script as a subprocess:

```py
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

duration = 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(duration):
        now = datetime.now()
        timestamp = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
        print(f"[{timestamp}]: {i+1}/{duration} seconds have elapsed...")
        time.sleep(1)

    print(f"This string is being printed to sys.stderr.", file=sys.stderr)
    print(f"So is this one...", file=sys.stderr)
```

If I run a subprocess normally, the expected result happens: the stdout is printed line by line, in real time.

When I pack this code in a Python executable zip (using Bazel's Python Rules, but follows the same structure as is outlined by https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html), nothing is printed into the console until the process finishes or dies, at which point every line written to stdout gets printed to the console. The timestamps from the test code are correct:

```
[2024-01-16 11:29:47.169]: 1/3 seconds have elapsed...
[2024-01-16 11:29:48.169]: 2/3 seconds have elapsed...
[2024-01-16 11:29:49.174]: 3/3 seconds have elapsed...
This string is being printed to sys.stderr.
So is this one...
```

How can I get real-time stdout when the code is packed in an executable zip?

Comment: There is buffering in the stdout pipeline.  What commands are you running?  Are they other Python scrtipts?

Comment: And as an unrelated side note, the walrus operator should not be a first choice.  Instead of `while line := process.stdout.readline():`, prefer `for line in process.stdout:`.

Comment: I am running other Python scripts as well as `docker` and `git` commands.

Comment: Have you tried the [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) envvar?

Answer (score 0):

Following [AKX's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) suggestion, setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` envvar fixes this problem.